# Detect missing packets

Tags: opencv, javacv

I am using JavaCV for grabbing frames from rtsp stream, but sometimes I get error like this:

```
[h264 @ 000000000049a180] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 000000000049a180] RTP: missed 14 packets
[h264 @ 000000000049a180] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 000000000049a180] RTP: missed 54 packets[h264 @ 000000001371e700] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 000000001371e700] concealing 1027 DC, 1027 AC, 1027 MV errors in P frame
```

And when I get this packet the image becomes very bad and I dont want to use it.
Is there any way to detect if there are missed packets in stream and if the frame is bad?

Comment: Isn't the entire idea of a stream that certain frames will be bad? If you want reliable images, you shouldn't use RTP.